# removeAttr() and remove() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use `removeAttr()` and `remove()` to remove a `<div>`, but seems like it doesn't work. Since I have $('#div1').removeAttr('style').remove(); in the last line of the javascript, shouldn't that the `<div>` only appear just a moment? I am not sure if javascript is event-driven programming or top-down programming? Or depends on the code.

I want to do that because I want to delete and clear the `<div>` every time before I drag a new `<div>`, and I try to put that line of code everywhere, it doesn't work.

I am not a computer science major, please forgive my ignorance. But I don't understand why the last line doesn't execute? 
If you can help, I am very appreciated. Thank you very much.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dragging = false;
  var clickedX, clickedY;

  // right click event
  $("#displayWindow").mousedown(function(e) {
    // when the mouse is pressed, the div is appended to the displayWindow
    if (e.button == 2) {
      // append the div start at the location that we click
      $("#displayWindow").append("<div id='div1'></div>");
      // get the coordinate where we clicked and set the div begin with that position
      clickedX = e.pageX;
      clickedY = e.pageY;
      $('#div1').css({
        top: clickedY,
        left: clickedX
      });
      dragging = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // holding on the mouse button, change the size of the div
  $("#displayWindow").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (dragging) {
      var mouseOnX = e.pageX;
      var mouseOnY = e.pageY;
      // allow user drag the selection box in 4 different direction
      $('#div1').css({
        top: Math.min(clickedY, mouseOnY),
        left: Math.min(clickedX, mouseOnX),
        height: Math.abs(mouseOnY - clickedY),
        width: Math.abs(mouseOnX - clickedX)
      });
    }
  }); // end on

  $(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
    dragging = false;
  });

  // when clicked again, the menu fade out, and the div disappear
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.button == 0) {
      // remove the selection box div
      $('#div1').remove();
    }
  });

  // prevent the default contextmenu on the display window
  document.getElementById('displayWindow').oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
  };
}); // end ready
```

```css
 #displayWindow {
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid;
   height: 600px;
   width: 800px;
 }
 #div1 {
   background-color: lightgreen;
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0.3;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayWindow">
  <svg height="130" width="150" style="position:absolute; left:200; top:200;" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Major problem...if you remove it... it's gone forever and your mouse event code won't find it. Also...really don't need to remove style if you plan to remove whole element. I think what you probably want though is `empty()` so that element remains. Not really clear what your goal is and how you expect this UI to work

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you are trying to do. but you can just .hide() the div and use the div class as a selector to avoid conflicts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have is not with the removal. The issues are:

- You add an event handler to the `mousemove` event, **every** time you right click. This is not right. You need to bind the `mousemove` handler only once, so move that code outside of the `mousemove` event handler. As a consequence, also declare of `clickedX` and `clickedY` variables at the `ready` function level;
- The mousemove event gives no information about buttons being pressed, so `e.button` will be 0 always. Instead you should keep track of whether the mouse button is pressed with a variable, and reset that variable when you detect a `mouseup` event on the document. This is not perfect, but probably good enough;

Some other notes:

- The `div` you add has no `style` attribute, so it has no effect to do `removeAttr('style')`. However, the `remove()` works;
- You can change several `css` styles in one `css()` call, by passing an object with key/value pairs.
- There is no use in returning `true` from an event handler.
- Although you mention in comments that the user can drag in all 4 directions, you have only allowed the box to move in one quadrant. You can support the 4 directions with a combination of `Math.min` and `Math.abs` calls.

Here is some adapted code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dragging = false;
    var clickedX, clickedY;
    // right click event
    $("#displayWindow").mousedown(function(e) {
        // when the mouse is pressed, the div is appended to the displayWindow
        if (e.button == 2) {
            $('#div1').remove(); // remove div that might still be there.
            // append the div start at the location that we click
            $("#displayWindow").append("<div id='div1'></div>");
            // get the coordinate where we clicked and set the div begin with that position
            clickedX = e.pageX;
            clickedY = e.pageY;
            $('#div1').css({top: clickedY, left: clickedX});
            dragging = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    // holding on the mouse button, change the size of the div
    $("#displayWindow").on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (dragging) {
            var mouseOnX = e.pageX;
            var mouseOnY = e.pageY;
            // allow user to drag the selection box in 4 different directions
            $('#div1').css({
                top: Math.min(clickedY, mouseOnY), 
                left: Math.min(clickedX, mouseOnX),
                height: Math.abs(mouseOnY - clickedY), 
                width: Math.abs(mouseOnX - clickedX)
            });
        }
    }); 

    $(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
        dragging = false;
    });
    
    // when clicked the div disappears
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (e.button == 0) {
            // remove the selection box div
            $('#div1').remove();
        }
    });

    // prevent the default contextmenu on the display window
    document.getElementById('displayWindow').oncontextmenu = function() {
        return false;
    };

    $('#div1').remove();
}); // end ready
```

```css
 #displayWindow {
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid;
   height: 600px;
   width: 800px;
 }
 #div1 {
   background-color: lightgreen;
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0.3;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayWindow">
  <svg height="130" width="150" style="position:absolute; left:200; top:200;" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I am appreciated your help, your detail explanation and helping notes are very valuable for me. May I ask more question? I edited my code to what I want to achieve instead of testing the error. I notice the problem is that after I drag the first box, and then drag the second one, the coordinate of the first div remained. That is not what I want. I want the first div and the second div totally independent. In you try to drag a box and then just right click on somewhere else, the box just shifted to other location. Thank you very much

Comment: I added `$('#div1').remove();` in the right-mouse click code. Is this what you want?

Comment: I am appreciated, this completely solve my problem, thank you very much